# SPFieldUserValue and SPPrincipal

Tags: spmetal, spprincipal

I have a complex application that have several field of type UserMulti. These fields can accept either SPUser or SPGroup or a combination of both kind.

I have in my code the ID and the name of a SPPrincipal object. How can I get the corresponding SPPrincipal object?

I have this code :

```
    public static SPPrincipal GetPrincipal(SPWeb web, int principalID, string principalName)
    {
        return web.AllUsers.Cast<SPPrincipal>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == principalID && u.Name == principalName) ??
            web.SiteGroups.Cast<SPPrincipal>().SingleOrDefault(g => g.ID == principalID && g.Name == principalName);
    }
```

But that looks a bit weird to my eyes.

PS: I have ids and names because my value are coming from SPMetal, where fields of type UserMulti are created as one `IList<int?> userIds` and `IList<string> userImnName`

**[Edit]** I just realized that both SPGroup and SPUser are stored in the UserInformationList. So I can rely on Ids, I don't have to test the name.

My code is then slightly simplified :

```
    public static SPPrincipal GetPrincipal(SPWeb web, int principalID)
    {
        return web.AllUsers.Cast<SPPrincipal>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == principalID) ??
            web.SiteGroups.Cast<SPPrincipal>().SingleOrDefault(g => g.ID == principalID);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is not simpler solution that this one :

```
public static SPPrincipal GetPrincipal(SPWeb web, int principalID)
{
    return web.AllUsers.Cast<SPPrincipal>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == principalID) ??
        web.SiteGroups.Cast<SPPrincipal>().SingleOrDefault(g => g.ID == principalID);
}
```

Feel free to suggest another approach if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this by querying against the `web.SiteGroups` collection and the `web.AllUsers` collection, just as you have done, however I didn't cast. I instantiated an `SPPrincipal` to `null` and then set it equal to the `SPGroup` or `SPUser` before returning it.

Here's an example using iteration rather than Linq:

```
    private SPPrincipal GetPrincipal(SPSite spsSite, string strName)
    {
        SPPrincipal sppGroup = null;

        // Get user, if user is valid
        if (SPUtility.IsLoginValid(spsSite, strName))
        {
            sppGroup = spsSite.RootWeb.EnsureUser(strName); // <== Here I did not cast
        }
        else // Otherwise look for a group
        {
            foreach (SPGroup spgGroup in spsSite.RootWeb.SiteGroups)
            {
                if (spgGroup.Name.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ==
                    strName.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    sppGroup = spgGroup; // <== and here I did not cast
                                         //  which is what I was talking about
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sppGroup; // <== May be null here
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your answer.

Comment: The code will probably help.

Comment: More clear now :)